# mathtt with iwona font

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'm trying to use typewriter font in math mode using iwona fonts, but the result ends up being typeset in the iwona text font.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Math: $x^2+y^2=z^2$.\\
Texttt: \texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz} \\
Mathtt: $\mathtt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz}$
\end{document}
```

I would like the Mathtt line to look just like the Texttt line.  Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `\texttt{}` in math mode.  Is that an option for you, or do you need it in `\mathtt`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, in a few instances, the things I want typeset in mathtt will be in exponents or bases, in which case the sizes will be wrong.  Try $x^{\texttt{y}}$ to see what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a bug in the `iwona` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{iwona}{OT1}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Math: $x^2+y^2=z^2$.\\
Texttt: \texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz} \\
Mathtt: $\mathtt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz}$
\end{document}
```

The package has `\rmdefault` instead of `\ttdefault`, which explains the unexpected behavior.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This is even better (mathastext.sty isn't in the distribution I'm using).

Comment: @PatMorin I consider it a bug, as it does something completely unexpected. I can understand using `\rmdefault` for `\mathrm`, `\mathit` and `\mathsf`, as the default font is Iwona (which is sans serif) but not for `\mathtt`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't disagree.  It certainly wasn't what I was expecting.

Answer (score 6):

This will give you typewriter text in `\mathtt`, while leaving the remainder of math mode unchanged (I believe).

EDITED to place `fontenc` first in line of the packages, which was suggested in a nice comment by jfbu, so as to make sure `mathastext` got applied to the OT1 math exclusions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Math: $x^2+y^2=z^2$.\\
Texttt:~ \texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
Mathtt: $\mathtt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$\\

$x^{y\mathtt{y}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is better to move `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to before `mathastext`, else the "mathastextification" will not apply to `<`, `>`, `\ `, `|`, `{`, `}` which are not available in `OT1` encoding (except for mono-type fonts).