# dvips.sty missing from recent Texlive distro

Tags: graphics, color, texlive, dvips

I am trying to increase my access to a larger palette of predefined colors. One way to do that is outlined in the LaTeX Wikibook (Section 8, p. 87 ff. of the pdf version, [corresponding online version](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Predefined_colors)), by calling the `xcolor` package with options, thus:
...

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
...
```

This didn't work. Checking the Xcolor manual (section 2.1.2, p.7) says that "usenames" is an obsolete option.

So I tried these variations without "usenames", and none of them work:
...

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
...
```

I am also getting an error message after compiling, "cannot find dvips.sty".....this despite the fact that I've used the the Texlive complete distribution just two weeks ago.

Any ideas about what is going amok here?

Comment: Please show a full minimal but failing example. That makes it easier for others to copy your code and test it.

Comment: You might also want to list exactly which latex installation you are using as you example lines works just fine for me using both pdflatex and latex on texlive 2022.

Comment: And say what you mean by "it didn't work"

Comment: the error means you have \usepackage{dvips} which you should remove, but you have not shown any code that produces this

Comment: I have 11 versions of TeX Live on the machine I'm working on, from 2012 to 2022 and in none of them I can find `dvips.sty` and I believe there has never been such a file in the TeX distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue; by the way, no file `dvips.sty` has ever existed in the TeX universe, as far as I know.

The `hyperref` package should be loaded *last*, with a few exceptions that aren't among the packages you load.

I suggest to reorganize your preamble in order to have separate sections for packages and for setup.

I added setting `headheight` in `geometry` because so `fancyhdr` keeps asking otherwise.

Instead of `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{iwona}` it's better to load the `iwona` package (that also offers support for math).

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[
  inner=4cm,
  bottom=2in,
  outer=3cm,
  left=2in,
  headheight=14.5pt, % <--- fancyhdr tells you this
]{geometry}

% general use
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% text elements
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
%\usepackage{fontawesome5} % loaded by awesomebox

% general setup
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{minitoc}

% fonts
\usepackage[
  math, % comment if you really want math in a different font
]{iwona}

% symbols
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}

% temporary usage during document preparation
% don't forget to comment them out for the
% final version
\usepackage{todo}
%\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{lipsum}

% hyperref should come last
\usepackage{hyperref}

% setup
\pagestyle{fancy}
% don't forget to do something about the page style

\begin{document}

This is printed in Iwona, also for math
\[
\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `math` option you get

[image]

However, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114834/4427 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117449/4427 for using IwonaMath.

Answer (score 1):

To everyone--thanks for your patience as I learn how to ask better questions in this forum!
I have since discovered the package {mwe}, which will make it much easier to post some illustrative code in future questions.
***Meanwhile, In the present situation:***

I used {mwe} to test my color-problem code (i.e., wherein the "dvips.sty" error was generated).

I discovered that I  *could*
get access to the extra named colors {xcolor} using dvipsnames, ***if*** I employed the absolutely minimal preamble.

I then added the other packages that I had originally employed, in random order, one at a time, until I discovered that the call for a dvips color name caused an error.

**Result:** It seems that the {hyperref} package was causing failures of xcolor/dvipsnames. I shuffled the packages {hyperref}, {graphicx} and {xcolor}, and eventually found an ordering that worked; here it is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{todo}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inner=4cm, bottom=2in, outer=3cm,left=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{minitoc}
```

Comment: Quite wrong, sorry: `hyperref` must be last in this case. *Don't* load `mwe` for real world documents.